# Registering a Fargate service ELB target with correct port using CDK?

Tags: aws-fargate, aws-cdk, amazon-elb

I'm trying to add a fargate service as an Application Load Balancer target but it keeps getting the wrong container port. The task definition has two containers: an app on port 8080 and an nginx reverse proxy on port 443. When I try to wire these together via the CDK the target registration always gets port 8080. I can't seem to find a method or set of props that lets me tell the CDK which container's port to use. Or maybe I am and it's ignoring it? What am I missing?

Here's a trimmed down example construct:

```
export class CdkFargateElbStack extends cdk.Stack {

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'Vpc', { maxAzs: 2 });

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'Cluster', {
      vpc: vpc,
    });

    const taskDef = new FargateTaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDefinition');

    const appContainer = new ContainerDefinition(this, 'AppContainer', {
      image: ContainerImage.fromRegistry(APP_IMAGE),
      taskDefinition: taskDef,
    });
    appContainer.addPortMappings({
      hostPort: 8080,
      containerPort: 8080
    });
    const proxyContainer = new ContainerDefinition(this, 'ProxyContainer', {
      image: ContainerImage.fromRegistry(PROXY_IMAGE),
      taskDefinition: taskDef,
    })
    proxyContainer.addPortMappings({
      hostPort: 443,
      containerPort: 443,
    });

    const service = new FargateService(this, 'Service', {
      cluster: cluster,
      taskDefinition: taskDef,
      assignPublicIp: true,
      desiredCount: 1,
      vpcSubnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
      }),
    });

    const alb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'LoadBalancer', {
      vpc: vpc,
      internetFacing: true,
      ipAddressType: elb.IpAddressType.IPV4,
      vpcSubnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
      })
    });

    const tg = new ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'TargetGroup', {
      protocol: elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
      port: 443,
      vpc: vpc,
      targetType: elb.TargetType.IP,
      targets: [ service ],
    });

    const listener = alb.addListener('Listener', {
      protocol: elb.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
      port: 443,
      certificateArns: [ CERTIFICATE_ARN ],
      defaultTargetGroups: [tg]
    });

    const rule = new ApplicationListenerRule(this, 'rule', {
      listener,
      priority: 1,
      pathPattern: '*',
      targetGroups: [ tg ],
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the resulting target registrations. I need the port here to be 443.
[image: target registrations screenshot]

Comment: I should probably mention that I did try the path of using the `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` pattern, but got hung up on the requirement of specifying `domainName` and `domainZone` when using the HTTPS protocol. The hosted zones for the particular domain I'm using are managed in a different AWS account and I don't need/want this CDK stack to manipulate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation from `ecs.FargateService.loadBalancerTarget`, the container which will be selected as the ALB target is the first essential container from the task definition.

To use other containers create a service reference like this:

```
const sTarget = service.loadBalancerTarget({
  containerName: 'MyContainer',
  containerPort: 1234
}));
```

Then add `sTarget` to the targetGroup services.

Comment: This is correct! And this is exactly what I did after discovering that method existed, although for the life of me I can't find/remember where. Anyway, points to you for the anwser!